# Need to compare array in Marklogic with xquery

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-10

I need to compare array in MarkLogic with Xquery .

Query parameters:

```
{
  "list": {
    "bookNo": 13,
    "BookArray":[20,21,22,23,24,25]
  }
}
```

Sample Data:

```
{
"no":01'
"arrayList"[20,25]
}

{
"no":02'
"arrayList"[20,27]
}

{
"no":03'
"arrayList"[20,23,25]
}
```

Output:

```
"no":01
"no":03
```

I need to return "no" where all values from arraylist should be match with bookArray.

Comment: Your sample has invalid JSON.  Please update so that people can more easily prototype and help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok.  You do not explain if the actual data is in the system or not.  So I did an example as if it is all in memory.

I chose to keep the sample in the MarkLogic JSON representation which has some oddities like number-nodes and array-nodes under the hood. To make it more readable if you dig into it, i used `fn:data()` to get less verbose. In all reality, if this was an in-memory operation and I could not use Javascript, then I would have converted the JSON structures to maps.

Here is a sample to help you explore.  I cleaned up the JSON to be valid and for my sample wrapped the three samples in a single array.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

let $param-as-json := xdmp:unquote('{
  "list": {
    "bookNo": 13,
    "BookArray":[20,21,22,23,24,25]
  }
}')

let $list-as-json := xdmp:unquote('[
  {
  "no":"01",
  "arrayList":[20,25]
  },
  {
  "no":"02",
  "arrayList":[20,27]
  },
  {
  "no":"03",
  "arrayList":[20,23,25]
  }
]')


let $my-list := fn:data($param-as-json//BookArray)
return for $item in $list-as-json/*
  let $local-list := fn:data($item//arrayList)
  let $intersection := fn:data($item//arrayList)[.=$my-list]  
  where fn:deep-equal($intersection, $local-list)
  return $item/no
```

Result:

```
01
03
```